# rqt plugins not working after possible change in python version

Tags: ros, rqt, rqt-bag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run any rqt related command( rqt_bag, rqt_image_view), I get the following error:

> 

PluginManager._discover() force discovery of plugins
RospkgPluginProvider._find_plugins() crawling for plugins of type 'qt_gui'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I re-installed ros-noetic and the issue didn't go away. Default python version is 3.8.10. I guess I manually removed previous python 2.7 due to some CUDA issue.
Would appreciate any suggestions and help. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410244/rqt-plugins-not-working-after-possible-change-in-python-version/) by [vocdex](https://answers.ros.org/users/111100/vocdex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got it working.
Probably, some conflict between different installations of pyqt5.
I just typed

> pip uninstall pyqt5

on command line.

---

Originally posted by [vocdex](https://answers.ros.org/users/111100/vocdex/) with karma: 21 on 2022-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1